# VueJS v-model dynamic inputs form

Tags: forms, vue.js, data-binding

I'm trying to build a form using vuejs to bind to the inputs which are generated dynamically like so:

```
<div v-for="item in items">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <input type="text" v-model="form.values[item.id].grade">
    <input type="text" v-model="form.values[item.id].comment">
</tr>

data: function () {
    return {
        form: {
            time: '',
            values: []
        },
        items: [
            {'id': 5, 'name': five},
            {'id': 3, 'name': three},
            {'id': 7, 'name': seven},
            {'id': 2, 'name': two},
            {'id': 4, 'name': four}
        ]
    }
}
```

Is there any way to actually make this work?

Comment: `item` is not an object, it's either a number or a string (according to the data you provided in the question).

Comment: @DecadeMoon Oops, sorry that was a mistake in my example. `items` is an array of objects.

Comment: The bindings you have will work, you just need to make sure that `form.values` (which should probably be an object instead of an array) contains properties for each of your items (key being the item `id` and value being an object with `grade` and `comment` properties). You cannot bind to a non-existent property.

Comment: @DecadeMoon That works for one but they all seem to bind to the same object. I don't get it.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/169)?